# Is it possible to have a static index field for Liferay using solr-web plugin?

Tags: solr, indexing, liferay, nutch

Can anyone tell me if I can associate a static index field for Liferay using the solr-web.plugin? Is there a way to define a static index in solr?

I need something similar to the following configuration in Nutch

```
<property> 
    <name>index.static</name> 
    <value>source:nutch</value> 
</property>
```

This will add the field "source" as an index and its value as "nutch" to all documents in Nutch. Anything similar to this for Liferay + Solr?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure for Liferay configuration, however you can add a default value in the `schema.xml` which will be applied to documents.

```
<field name="source" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" default="Nutch" />
```